# Apply multiple styles in a spreadhseet row while using axlsx in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreadsheet, axlsx

I am using axlsx gem to generate spreadsheets in rails.

I have around 25 columns in a row and I would like to apply:

1. bold font and blue background on column 1
2. blue background (WITHOUT bold font) on all the remaining columns 2 to 25.

How can I achieve this without having to write the style 25 times?

This is the current code I am using:

```
color_style = [gray_col1_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style, gray_style]

sheet.add_row [treasury_forecast.forecast_item, treasury_forecast.total, treasury_forecast.mtd, treasury_forecast.day1, treasury_forecast.day2, treasury_forecast.day3, treasury_forecast.day4, treasury_forecast.day5, treasury_forecast.day6, treasury_forecast.day7, treasury_forecast.day8, treasury_forecast.day9, treasury_forecast.day10, treasury_forecast.day11, treasury_forecast.day12, treasury_forecast.day13, treasury_forecast.day14, treasury_forecast.day15, treasury_forecast.day16, treasury_forecast.day17, treasury_forecast.day18, treasury_forecast.day19, treasury_forecast.day20, treasury_forecast.day21, treasury_forecast.day22, treasury_forecast.day23], :style => color_style
```

I have repeated gray_style for all columns except col1. Is there a way to apply a style to col1 and another style to all other columns without having to type the style name multiple times as I have done above?

Comment: Hi and welcome to [so]! Your posted question does not appear to include an attempt to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @lucascaro - I have added some code snippets to my question now. Hope it is okay now.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you apply blue background to the row and then apply bold style only in first cell of each column?

```
   sheet.add_row row_data, :style => blue_background_style
   sheet.rows[current_row].cells[0].style = bold_style
```